# What do you call a martial arts belt 'stripe' in Spanish?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, vocabulario-técnico

I'm trying to find the right word to use for a stripe in Jiu Jitsu; as you go up the levels you receive 4 stripes per belt colour. Would I use 'rayas'...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have practiced martial arts in the past, and where I come from, the word that I am familiar with  is:

> Punta

For example:

> El estudiante es cinta naranja **punta** verde.

Note that in other contexts, stripe might be translated as:

> franja

and as Diego mentioned,

> raya

.

Comment: Yes. Me too. I practiced Taekwon Do for so long and in Spanish we call it normally as "Punta <color>". eg. Punta amarilla (Yellow stripe), Punta verde (Green stripe), Punta azul (Blue stripe), Punta roja (Red stripe), Punta negra (Black stripe). When someone arrives to black belt, the degree is called Primer Dan (First Dan) 'til Noveno Dan (Ninth Dan). Depending on the martial art the Tenth Dan is unreachable because is reserved to the founder of the martial art.

Comment: Thank you! In jiu jitsu the stripes aren't coloured, but every belt has 4 stripes. I assume I could say 'soy cinta blanca con 3 puntas/rayas' and it would make sense?

Comment: No problem! And as you said, the "cinta blanca con tres puntas" sentence is completely correct.

Answer (score 3):

`Raya` seems to be appropriate for this context, like

> En el segundo nivel el cinturón es blanco con una raya naranja

I was surprises first time I was told that there are more levels beyond a black belt. I think in karate they are called *dans*. Probably other disciplines have their own names as well as their own color schemes for belts, but AFAIK, there is no specific term to describe these stripes.

I just google for some info and found the following table, which again uses **rayas** (example for the 7th Kyu) to convey *stripes*:

[image]

Nevertheless, take notice that the above is appropriate to describe the belt to some one, like me, who has no idea what it looks like. People who are already "in the business" and know what the belts looks like often refer to them as "blanco, blanco-amarillo (no mention to the stripe), blanco-rojo, etc.)